# getExtra() for Intent in Adapter Class

Tags: android, android-intent

**I am very beginner**

I can't seem to be able to use getExtra() when I am creating the Intent myIntent instance outside a method, I was able to use it inside the method which I called callEditActivity()

However, I am trying to pass the string values (of img0, img1...etc) to the String Array StringGalImages; I can't figure how; I have tried this.img inside CallEditActivity but the values weren't passed.

I have also tried explicit urls as img0 ="www.something.com/image.jpg" inside CallEditActivity , and couldn't pass it to the array.

It worked only when initializing the img0 outside the method but I can't do this the getExtra, I am obliged to use the getExtra only inside CallEditActivity.

So how I can get the value gotten from getExtra to the String Array?

```
public class ImageAdapter1 extends PagerAdapter {

Context context;

private String img0;
private String img1;
private String img2;
private String img3;
private String img4;

public void callEditActivity() {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, BirdsGalleryActivity.class);

    img0 = myIntent.getExtras().getString("IMG0");
    img1 = myIntent.getExtras().getString("IMG1");
    img2 = myIntent.getExtras().getString("IMG2");
    img3 = myIntent.getExtras().getString("IMG3");
    img4 = myIntent.getExtras().getString("IMG4");

}

private String[] StringGalImages = new String[] {

   img0,img1,img2,img3,img4

};
```

Answer (score 1):

you just created new `Intent` with this line:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, BirdsGalleryActivity.class);
```

how it should be fulfilled with extras? when you creating new `Intent` you are setting extras, not fetching/getting... there are `null`s only. your code is probably more "incomplete" (cutted before post?), because line:

```
img0 = myIntent.getExtras().getString("IMG0");
```

just after `Intent` creation should throw NPE for not-set-yet extras, from which you are trying to `getString`

EDIT:

create new array after fetching from extras (even if it is not possible with this code you posted...)

```
StringGalImages = new String[] {

   img0,img1,img2,img3,img4

};
```

or if you always have fixed numer of items in array you may use

```
StringGalImages[0] = myIntent.getExtras().getString("IMG0");
StringGalImages[1] = myIntent.getExtras().getString("IMG1");
...
```

`StringGalImages` declaration should be pasted above method

Comment: how should I do it?

Comment: Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, BirdsGalleryActivity.class); was created in another the BirdsGalleryActivity where I used putExtra.  I am just trying to get these values inside the Adapter class.

Comment: Ok so you are saying it's wrong to create an new intent in the adapter class. I am trying to use getIntent().getExtra() but it's not working in the Adapter class...(can't resolve method)

Comment: I'm not saying that you can't create new Intent inside `Adapter`. You can, but you are creating new `Intent` and then immediatelly trying to get from intents extras some `String`s... this isn't a way it works, read about starting new `Activties` and other contextual creatures

Comment: ^ Ok, I got that part, I shall use getIntent() to get the stored intent Extras in the previous (by putExtra's) activity

Comment: indeed! note methods [onNewIntent(Intent newIntent)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent)) and [onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult(int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent)), in which you may get _new_ intents. but generally using `getIntent` is a good way to get data from extras

Answer (score 1):

Ok I did that:

```
public class ImageAdapter1 extends PagerAdapter {



Context mContext;

private String img0;
private String img1;
private String img2;
private String img3;
private String img4;

public void callEditActivity() {

    Intent intent = ((Activity) mContext).getIntent();
    this.img0 = intent.getExtras().getString("IMG0");
    this.img1 = intent.getExtras().getString("IMG1");
    this.img2 = intent.getExtras().getString("IMG2");
    this.img3 = intent.getExtras().getString("IMG3");
    this.img4 = intent.getExtras().getString("IMG4");

    ((Activity) mContext).setResult(((Activity) mContext).RESULT_OK,
            intent);
    ((Activity) mContext).finish();
}


private String[] StringGalImages = new String[] {

   img0,img1,img2,img3,img4

};
```

But now how can I pass imgNs to the array StringGalImages?

Answer (score 0):

You are creating new Intent, then new intent dont have you extras that has put in BirdsGalleryActivity. You need get intent of BirdsGalleryActivity that was placed (putString).

I think that in BirdsGalleryActivity you need getIntent() and set you extras, and you pass this intent to Adapter.